# How to implement Broadcast Upload extension in landscape?

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, live-streaming, replaykit

I'm handling ReplayKit2 in iOS, i would like to rotate the CMSampleBuffer to landscape (It always portrait). Could you please advice me a way to do that ?

Here is my code

```
override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        switch sampleBufferType {
        case RPSampleBufferType.video:
            // Handle video sample buffer
            session.pushVideoBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            break
        case RPSampleBufferType.audioApp:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for app audio
            //session.pushAudioBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            break
        case RPSampleBufferType.audioMic:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for mic audio
            session.pushAudioBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            break
        @unknown default:
            // Handle other sample buffer types
            fatalError("Unknown type of sample buffer")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you got a way to landscape video buffer?

Comment: Yes, I resolved it. CMSampleBuffer -> CIImage -> oriented -> CMSampleBuffer

Please refer API open func oriented(_ orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) -> CIImage